# selected Row in datatable on primefaces

Tags: java, datatable, primefaces

I would like to obtein the Id of the selected row in a datable but instead i am getting the one selected before, not the current selectetion.
My code its the following

```
<p:dataTable id="translationsTable" var="translation" value="#{videoBean.lyric.polylrcList}" rowKey="#{translation.lang}" selectionMode="single" selection="#{videoBean.selected}"> 
                     <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="translationsTable"  process="translationsTable" oncomplete="alert(#{videoBean.selected.id});"/> 
</p:dataTable>
```

it should show the current id, but its always showing me the last one.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a workaround to solve this problem..
I am executing directly the javascript function from primefaces on row selected like that.

```
public void rowSelected(SelectEvent event) {
    selectedPolyLrc = (Polylrc) event.getObject(); 
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("alert( "+selectedPolyLrc.getId()+");");
    System.out.println("SELECTED AREA:" + selectedPolyLrc);
    //...
}
```

Like that im always assured that the javascript function will be executed after the row is selected

Answer (score 1):

```
 <p:dataTable id="translationsTable" var="translation" value="#{videoBean.lyric.polylrcList}"     rowKey="#{translation.lang}" selectionMode="single" selection="#{videoBean.selected}">

    <p:column>
        #{translation.id}
    </p:column>

    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="translationsTable"  process="translationsTable" oncomplete="alert(#{translation.id});"/> 

</p:dataTable>
```

You can use [www.primefaces.org](http://www.primefaces.org).

Comment: The problem its that once you select the column and the ajax event is trigger it will alert when complete, but from the last selection not from the current one selected.